# How to duplicate running docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have a docker container running

```
> docker container ls
                                                                                                                         
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS  NAMES
c5a24953e383  gradle  "bash"   22 minutes ago  Up 22 minutes  #      naughty_torvalds
```

Can I duplicate this running container and run it? What is the command for it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can create a new image from that container using the `docker commit` command:

```
docker commit c5a24953e383 newimagename
```

And then start a new container from that image:

```
docker run [...same arguments as the other one...] newimagename
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not copy volumes

Comment: That’s true, but the question wasn’t about copying volumes. The easiest way to do that is probably to mount the old and new volumes in a container and use `tar`. I suspect that process may be addressed in more detail elsewhere on this site, but if not you can open a new question.

Comment: but this does not copy things I have created in the running container, does it?

Comment: It does because of the `docker commit` in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sh
docker run --name duplicateImage --volumes-from Image -d -p 3000:80 nginix:latest
```

The `--volumes-from Image` duplicates the 'Image' container.

So you will now have a container named Image and a container named duplicateImage and they will contain the same image that is running (a container).

Comment: the argument is `--volumes-from` not `--volumes -from`.

Comment: I tried this method to get a new container with the same Python dependencies installed. However, the duplicated container comes up without those dependencies.

Comment: @sbmthakur this may have happened because this command duplicates an **image**, not the **container** itself. The original image didn't have these dependencies and while `--volumes-from` duplicates the volumes from the container, these dependencies may have been installed on the OS folder.